# how to block the repeated URL in URL Patterns to Exclude section in the HTTP Proxy Server settings in the JMeter

Tags: jmeter

In Workbench, we have use the Http(s) test script recorder to record the login and logout. While recording the follow URL(/Exception/HandleLoginError) has been recorded 10 more times, it is not in use for load testing. How to block the repeated URL.

And also i have use the URL Patterns to Exclude section(.*.(bmp|css|js|gif|ico|jpe?g|png|swf|woff|webm|ttf)). It is working fine.

Need solution for block the repeated URLs.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Did you try just .*/HandleLoginError or .*/HandleLoginError/.* if there is something further on the path? It's case sensitive, so watch out.

Comment: .*/HandleLoginError. It is working fine. Thanks Faflok

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below sample code is working fine. In path field write the below  format

.*/HandleLoginError.